# Como inserir uma única resposta certa na tag input?

Tags: html, html5, input

Eu quero que a tag input possua uma única resposta certa. Ao inserir uma resposta (aqui vamos chamá-la de "exemplo2"), vá para uma certa página (aqui, vamos usar "https://www.google.com.br").

Comment: Olá Shiro! Sua pergunta não explica nada. Faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e insira uma pergunta de acordo com as [regras do site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Caso seu objetivo, seja abrir uma determinada página Web de acordo com a resposta do usuário. Esta seria uma possível solução:

```js
function change(value){
switch(value){
case 'exemplo2':
   window.open('https://www.google.com.br');
}
}
```

```html
<input type='text' placeholder='Digite:' onchange='change(value)'/>
```

Se você testar em um navegador web, verá que ao responder 'exemplo2' uma nova página web com o endereço do Google será aberta.